# SQL Pivot example

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

EAV model

```
create table people_details
( id number
, name varchar2(30)
, det_number number
, det_text varchar2(30)
, prop_id number
);

create table properties
( id number
, description varchar2(30)
);

insert into properties values (1,'EYE COLOR');
insert into properties values (2,'INCOME');
insert into properties values (3,'EDUCATION');

INSERT INTO people_details VALUES (1,'JOHN',NULL,'BLUE',1);
INSERT INTO people_details VALUES (2,'JOHN',5000,NULL,2);
INSERT INTO people_details VALUES (3,'JOHN',NULL,'HIGHSCHOOL',3);
INSERT INTO people_details VALUES (4,'PHILIP',NULL,'GREEN',1);
INSERT INTO people_details VALUES (5,'PHILIP',7000,NULL,2);
INSERT INTO people_details VALUES (6,'PHILIP',NULL,'COLLEGE',3);
INSERT INTO people_details VALUES (7,'SANDY',NULL,'BROWN',1);
INSERT INTO people_details VALUES (8,'SANDY',9000,NULL,2);
INSERT INTO people_details VALUES (9,'SANDY',NULL,'COLLEGE',3);
```

Now select all the people with blue eyes or income above average.
This is what I did

```
WITH PEOPLE AS (
  SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT NAME, DESCRIPTION, NVL(DET_TEXT, TO_CHAR(DET_NUMBER)) AS DETAIL
    FROM PEOPLE_DETAILS PPL
    JOIN PROPERTIES PRO ON PPL.PROP_ID = PRO.ID
  )
  PIVOT (
    MAX(DETAIL)
    FOR DESCRIPTION IN ('EYE COLOR' as EYE_COLOR, 'EDUCATION' AS EDUCATION, 'INCOME' AS INCOME)
  )
)
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE EYE_COLOR = 'BLUE'
UNION
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE INCOME > (SELECT AVG(INCOME) FROM PEOPLE);
```

Is there some nicer way of doing this? Here i convert income to character and avg function probably does an implicit conversion. Not sure if it would work in a program.
How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this using `group by` and `having`:

```
with p as (
      select pd.name,
             max(case when p.description = 'EYE COLOR' then det_text end) as eye_color,
             max(case when p.description = 'INCOME' then cast(det_text as number) end) as income,
             max(case when p.description = 'EDUCATION' then det_text end) as education
      from people_details pd join
           properties p
           on pd.prop_id = p.id
      group by pd.name
     )
select p.*
from (select p.*, avg(income) over () as avg_income
      from p
     ) p
where income > avg_income or eye_color = 'BLUE';
```

One advantage to this approach is that you can immediately represent `income` as a number when it is calculated.

Comment: Not really correct or finished. We want all atributes out. I only get (John, Blue, null. null)